# enable_if using a constexpr bool test not working

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr, enable-if

I have a maths function that I want to be able to accept either a double, or a array/vector/container of doubles, and behave slightly differently.

I am attempting to use SFINAE and type traits to select the correct function.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool Iscontainer()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_class<T>::value && std::is_arithmetic<typename T::value_type>::value) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Function 1 (double):
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type g(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a double" << t << std::endl;
}

// Function 2 (vec), version 1:
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<IsContainer<T>()>::type g(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a container" << t[0] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v {1, 2};
    std::array<double, 2> a {1, 2};
    double d {0.1};

    g<>(v);
    g<>(a);
    g<>(d);  // error here
}
```

I get a compile time error:

```
../main.cpp:8:47: error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
     if constexpr (std::is_class<T>::value && std::is_arithmetic<typename     T::value_type>::value) {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

However, when I replace function 2 with:

```
// Function 2 (vec), version 2:
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value && std::is_arithmetic<typename T::value_type>::value>::type
g(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a vector" << t[0] << std::endl;
}
```

It works.

My problem is I don't understand why the first version does not work..
And I prefer the readability of the first version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it fails is simple. You do not invoke SFINAE, and when the compiler tries to evaluate the expressions it sees:

```
if constexpr (std::is_class<double>::value // this is fine it's false
   && std::is_arithmetic<typename double::value_type>::value // problem here!
)
```

The whole statement is evaluated, there is no short-circuit for the if. The closest solution to what you currently have is to explicitly split the `if`, so that the problematic part is discarded when `T` is not a class and the second check is nonsensical.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsVector()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_class<T>::value) {
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<typename T::value_type>::value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Function 1 (double):
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type g(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a double" << t << std::endl;
}

// Function 2 (vec), version 1:
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<IsVector<T>()>::type g(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a vector" << t[0] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v {1, 2};
    double d {0.1};

    g<>(v);
    g<>(d);  // error here
}
```

Alternatively I'd suggest a `using` alias:

```
template <typename T>
using IsVector2 = std::conjunction<typename std::is_class<T>, std::is_arithmetic<typename T::value_type> >;

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<IsVector2<T>::value>::type g(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a vector" << t[0] << std::endl;
}
```

You could also name it better. It doesn't really check whether `T` is a `vector`, or a container (after your edit). Your current definition is a bit loose as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that simple overload does the job:

```
template <typename T>
void g(T const & t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a double" << t << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void g(const std::vector<T>& t)
{
    std::cout << "this is for a vector" << t[0] << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffe4886eb20b2068)

Your problem is that `T::value_type` is evaluated for `double`
You have hard error (SFINAE doesn't occur there) before short circuit evaluation.
you might place this condition the constexpr part.

You might rewrite your function:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsVector()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_class<T>::value) {
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<typename T::value_type>::value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e18483de7b75d16)

Your second version use SFINAE

```
// Function 2 (vec), version 2:
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value
                        && std::is_arithmetic<typename T::value_type>::value>::type
// SFINAE happens here for double                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
g(T const & t)
```

Comment: hmm, that's true, what if I want it to work for std::arrays as well? Still interested in why this didn't work

Comment: @dddd4 Add another overload then?

Comment: What about types I am not aware of that provide a [] interface to their data?

Comment: @dddd4: I also added explanation of your problem with solution using your code.

Comment: So your traits function is not what you expect neither, you might instead want a traits `has _bracket_operator` or similar.